# what is .class in java?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args)  
{  
    // Let's print the classloader name of current class.   
    //Application/System classloader will load this class 
    Class b= int.class; 
    Class c=ClassLoaderExample.class; 
    ClassLoaderExample a= new ClassLoaderExample(); 
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

what is .class in here and what it specifies? Are c and a different?

Comment: According to this, both a and c are objects of ClassLoaderExample class, then why a.getCalss and c.getClass has different outputs?

Comment: No, it's same as above. But doesn't clear my confusion. I am trying to understand. Perhaps it's my low grasping power, but it's still unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `class` is a definition of type, an `object` is an instance of type. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

`c` is an object of type `Class`. So, `c`, as such, is "an object of certain type", but it's *value* conveys information about the type of some other entity.

Yes, it's confusing for beginners. Fortunately, one doesn't have to use `Class` type often.

Comment: So a and c are both objects, but of different classes?

Comment: that's exactly what you see in your code: `Class c = ...; ClassLoaderExample a = ...;`

Comment: Let me articulate. Here c is object of class Class. But it refers to class ClassloaderExample. Just like b is object of class Calss but refers to int class. So when I print b, it's int but b.getClass(), it's java.lang.Class. But a is object of class ClassLoaderExample, and a.getClass() will say same.

Comment: Am I going correctly?

Comment: `a.getClass` is a method that returns a value, that is same as `c`. I don't really understand, sorry, but what is the confusion here?

Comment: `b` and `c` both are objects of `Class` type (which is a parametrized type, by the way, but let's not get there yet). `a` is a "regular" object, of `ClassLoaderExample` type.

Comment: Oh yes! Got it. The previous question does answer my query. Thanks! Will close this